# Powershell contains - match on partial string and list?

Tags: powershell, match, contains

I have this situation in my script:

```
$Excludes = "Commvault","Veeam"

$testuser = 'DOMAIN\vCommvaultConnect'
$Excludes | ForEach-Object {
    If ($testuser.Contains($_)) {
    Write-Host "Found"
    }
}
```

Is this the most efficient way to test for this or is there a faster way to match a user to each of those excluded words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, using Regex search groups

```
$Excludes = "Commvault","Veeam"

$SearchRegex_Excludes = ($Excludes | % { "(" + ($_) + ")" }) -join "|"
# sample regex pattern result - (Commvault)|(Veeam)

$testuser = "DOMAIN\vCommvaultConnect"

if ( $testuser -match $SearchRegex_Excludes ) { "Found" } else { "Not Found " }
```

Comment: Is this more efficient or faster than the original? If yes - why?

Comment: It's both, Just use measure-command on both. Thanks Karthick, this is what I was trying to remmeber how to do. The excludes variable is only used for this, so I can define it as a Regex group anyway: $Excludes = "Commvault|Veeam"

Comment: I did measure. OK. If that difference is what matters for you. ;-)

Comment: Can you explain why this is more efficient?